# python regex to replace repetitive pattern "number and space"

Tags: python, regex

```
input = 3136 -2 1806481261 191415576 883713178 259822501 0 79439 0 0 0
```

I want to extract the value 259822501 from the above input.

I can extract it using following regex :

```
\d+\s-?\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+)[\d\\s]+.*
```

If you clearly see in the above regex, the pattern "\d+\s+" is repetitive.

Looking for more efficient regular expression here.

Comment: Does it need to be regex? If its always in that format then can't you just split on space and take the 6th element?

Comment: Yes, I need a regex here.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a regex? It appears you are simply extracting the 6th white-space separated number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+
```

can be relplaced by

```
(?:\d+\s+){4}
```

- `(?:` for non capturing group

[can be checked here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dmeWO3/1/), however there's a probleme with the last digit because of [\d\s] following

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the repetitions using a (non-)captured group with the repetition operator `{}` after that to indicate the number of repetitions:

```
^(?:-?\d+\s+){5}(\d+)
```

As `259822501` comes after 5 repititions of `-?\d+\s+`, i have used `{5}`. Now, the captured group 1 will have your desired output.

**Example:**

```
In [39]: s
Out[39]: '3136 -2 1806481261 191415576 883713178 259822501 0 79439 0 0 0'

In [40]: re.search(r'^(?:-?\d+\s+){5}(\d+)',  s).group(1)
Out[40]: '259822501'
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming input is a space separated string, and based on the regex the number you want to extract is specifically the 6th number, you could use `split()` and indexing:

```
>>> input = '3136 -2 1806481261 191415576 883713178 259822501 0 79439 0 0 0'
>>> input.split()
['3136', '-2', '1806481261', '191415576', '883713178', '259822501', '0', '79439', '0', '0', '0']
>>> input.split()[5]
'259822501'
```